# Laravel Eloquent - Return Where Has + Where

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have customers that have many parcels through orders.

```
public function parcels()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Parcel::class, Order::class);
    }
```

I want to return customers that have parcels more than 0 with successful status only.
But I don't know how to add conditions of parcel status. Currently, this statement gives me a list of customers that have parcels.
`$customers = Customer::has('parcels', '>' , 0)->get();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `whereHas` method.

```php
$customers = Customer::whereHas('parcels', function ($query) {
    $query->where('status', 'successful');
})->get();
```